# How to hot add a new disk with virsh attach-disk?

Tags: virtualization, lvm

I'm trying to add a new LVM disk to my guest machine (Ubuntu 14.04.1) by doing 
the following on the **host:**

```
lvcreate -L 14G -n vm_vm005_data3 vg00 
virsh attach-disk vm005 /dev/vg00/vm_vm005_data3 --target sdd --persistent --live
```

Disk is attached successfully. However, if I dmesg the guest I see no change.

The disk is visible once I reboot the guest, but I want to do this with no downtime.

Some web resources have pointed to the need to have modules      **acpiphp** and **pci_hotplug** installed, but there are no such modules on this guest. There is an **acpiphp_ibm** one, but can't be loaded (*modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'acpiphp_ibm': No such device*).

How can I add the new device without a reboot?